# php codeigniter - form helper - How to implement set_value on radio input

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, radio-button

I am in the process of setting up a feedback form for my site using codeigniters form helper.

My form has been created and validation implemented, all works.

My only problem is adding the set_value() function to repopulate the form if an error occurs.

I can't get it to work on my radio inputs, how do you add the set_value() function to a radio type.

Code:

```
      <ul> 
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'newspaper_advert', set_value('found_by')); ?> Newspaper advert</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'press_release', set_value('found_by')); ?> Press release</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'text_message', set_value('found_by')); ?> Text message</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'email', set_value('found_by')); ?> Email</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'refferal', set_value('found_by')); ?> Referred to by a friend</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'telemarketing', set_value('found_by')); ?> Telemarketing</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'leaflet_flyer', set_value('found_by')); ?> Leaflet or flyer</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'radio', set_value('found_by')); ?> Radio</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'television', set_value('found_by')); ?> Television</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'internet_advert', set_value('found_by')); ?> Internet advert</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'search_engine', set_value('found_by')); ?> Search engine</li>
          <li><?php echo form_radio('found_by', 'none', set_value('found_by')); ?> None of the above</li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`set_value` only works on inputs and textareas. you need `set_radio`

> **set_radio()**
>
> Permits you to display radio buttons in the state they were submitted. 
>       This function is identical to the set_checkbox() function above.

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1" <?php echo set_radio('myradio', '1', TRUE); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2" <?php echo set_radio('myradio', '2'); ?> />
```

From doc page: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me, im using values 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2, any clue?

Comment: @Chumillas, are you passing 0 and 1 as strings in the `set_radio` function?

Comment: Yes, as same as you do

Comment: The problem is when the user didn't upload an image in the form, the validation breaks with 'You did not select a file to upload.' and the set_radio doesn't works anymore. If the user upload an image the set_radio works when another field breaks the validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= form_radio('found_by', 'newspaper_advert', $found_by == 'newspaper_advert'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works for me:

**Gender:**

```
< ?php echo form_radio("gender", "Female", NULL, set_radio('gender', 'Female')); ?>Female

< ?php echo form_radio("gender", "Male", NULL, set_radio('gender', 'Male')); ?>Male
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1" <?php echo  set_radio('myradio', '1'); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2" <?php echo  set_radio('myradio', '2'); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="3" <?php echo  set_radio('myradio', '3'); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="4" <?php echo  set_radio('myradio', '4'); ?> />
```

it is so easy....

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php echo form_radio( array( 'name'=> 'age_group','id'=>'age_group','class'=> 'input-xsmall focused inputError','type'=>'radio',set_radio('age_group', 'under 18', TRUE) ) ). "under 18"; ?><br />
            <?php echo form_radio( array( 'name'=> 'age_group','id'=>'age_group','class'=> 'input-xsmall focused inputError','type'=>'radio',set_radio('age_group', '18 to 29', TRUE) ) ). "18 to 29"; ?><br />
            <?php echo form_radio( array( 'name'=> 'age_group','id'=>'age_group','class'=> 'input-xsmall focused inputError','type'=>'radio',set_radio('age_group', '30 to 49', TRUE) ) ). "30 to 49"; ?><br />
            <?php echo form_radio( array( 'name'=> 'age_group','id'=>'age_group','class'=> 'input-xsmall focused inputError','type'=>'radio',set_radio('age_group', 'above 49', TRUE) ) ). "above 49"; ?>
```

It is right code in view ??